# Urldecode in PHP

Tags: php, urldecode

I was wondering...my friend and I were having a debate over this.
Is there anything I could pass in the url to get to the echo call (The one that says "Yay potatoes!!!" sorry was unclear)?

```
<?
if(eregi("potato",$_GET[id])) {
  echo("<p>Awww no potatoes :c </3</p>");
  exit();
}

$_GET[id] = urldecode($_GET[id]);
if($_GET[id] == "potato")
{
  echo "<p>Yay potatoes!!!!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: [`eregi` is deprecated.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You can double-encode a character (or more)

```
?id=%2570otato
```

PHP will decode the first one and give you:

```
$_GET['id'] = "%70otato"
```

This will pass `eregi()` without exiting.  Then, you run `urldecode()` on it, which gives you `potato`.

Yay, potatoes.  Codepad example:  http://codepad.org/IYwizCXK